# MediaElement Speed ratio for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I'd like to manually set speed ratio for my `MediaElement` object in **Windows Phone 8**. There is no `SpeedRatio` property anymore, and I don't seem to be able to use `SmoothStreamingMediaElement`  (part of `Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming` namespace).

Is there any other way to set my `MediaElement` speed (I need to slow the playback down) for Windows Phone 8?

Thanks!

Comment: I already tried to find a solution to slow down or speed up music for a DJ application. But no API is currently available. Wait until Microsoft decides.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, sure, will do (sorry for inconvenience)

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback! In this case, the OP has to provide the **code** that leads to the problem, so closing the question is the only way to vote here btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Player Framework (https://playerframework.codeplex.com/). With this framework you can use the `Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming` namespace and set the playback rate.